# The usage of 'which' and 'that'

Tags: relative-pronouns, comparison

I learned that *which* and *that* are interchangeable; and I also learned that *which8 can be converted to *and it*.

Then how about these sentences?

> 1. In this chapter we presented a new context sharing scheme within 
>      a pervasive and ad-hoc network **that** can address the problem in
>      many-to-many communication: a large number of context exchanges.
> 2. In this chapter we presented a new context sharing scheme within a pervasive and ad-hoc network **which** can address the problem in
>      many-to-many communication: a large number of context exchanges.
> 3. In this chapter we presented a new context sharing scheme within a pervasive and ad-hoc network, **which** can address the problem in
>      many-to-many communication: a large number of context exchanges.

1. Do 1 and 2 convey the exactly same meaning?
2. How about 3? I think 3 is the correct statement, as what addresses the problem is "scheme" not "network" so there should be a *which" to explicitly show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *that* and *which* are both [relative pronouns](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns), I wouldn't call them [interchangeable](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/which-versus-that-0). It all boils down to whether or not the information in the clause is essential to the meaning of the sentence.

That is to say, if the clause is [restrictive](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/), meaning you can't eliminate it without changing the meaning, then use [*that*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that). On the other hand, if the clause is [nonrestrictive](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaClauses__Restrictive_and_Nonrest.htm), meaning that the information contained within the clause is extraneous then use [*which*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/which). Typically, clauses using *which* are set off from the sentence with [commas](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/why-commas-matter).

So in answer to your question, semantically number one and number two mean the same thing; however, typically number two would be the [correct choice](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that) as the information can be removed without changing the meaning of the sentence (i.e. it is a nonrestrictive clause); but if I were editing you, I'd correct it to number three, as it's customary to set nonrestrictive clauses apart from the rest of the sentence.